# Stripe payment API: How to present Google Pay as a payment type (web)?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm following a [guide](https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-subscription-payments/blob/main/public/javascript/app.js) on how to create a checkout page for a product via the stripe API. I can set the "payment_method_types", but the [list of payment_method_types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) does not show any option for Google Pay or Apple Pay.

Edit: As mentioned in my answer, I thought the Google Pay option would just show up, but it's not showing up on the billing/checkout portal. I also checked that Google Pay is set to "on" in my Stripe account settings. I even went through the effort of creating a GPay account with valid payment info, and it still did not show up even after I logged in via google and went to the checkout page.

Code:

```
const checkoutSession = {
    automatic_tax: true,
    tax_id_collection: true,
    collect_shipping_address: true,
    allow_promotion_codes: true,
    line_items: [selectedPrice],
    success_url: window.location.href,
    cancel_url: window.location.href,
    metadata: {
      key: 'value',
    },
};
checkoutSession.mode = 'subscription';
checkoutSession.payment_method_types = ['card'];

const docRef = await db
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .collection('checkout_sessions')
    .add(checkoutSession);
// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
    console.log("entered Snap: ", snap.data());
    const { error, url } = snap.data();
    if (error) {
      // Show an error to your customer and then inspect your function logs.
      alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((b) => (b.disabled = false));
    }
    if (url) {
      window.location.assign(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer was there is an additional condition that must be satisfied that isn't documented anywhere: Google Pay and Apple Pay only show up if `automatic_tax` is false OR `shipping_address_collection` countries are set.

I was able to fix the issue after setting automatic_tax to false, but still got bugged behavior with automatic_tax set to true and shipping_address_collection having 'US' as a country. Perhaps in the latter case I did something wrong. In any case, automatic_tax to false seems to resolve the issue.

I got this tip from Stripe Support and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS DOESN'T WORK. Original answer below.

Found the [answer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#apple-pay-and-google-pay)

> When you turn on cards in the Dashboard, it enables Apple Pay and
> Google Pay too. When you enable automatic_payment_methods or pass card
> in payment_method_types on the PaymentIntent, your customer also sees
> Apple Pay and Google Pay. These payment methods require you to serve
> your application over HTTPS in development and production.
> Additionally, you need to verify your domain for Apple Pay.
>
> Stripe only displays Apple Pay and Google Pay on their corresponding
> platforms. Customers also need an active card associated with their
> account.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work. I specified "card" but don't see Google Pay anywhere.